# Is there a easy way to change a directory in application iml to build folder for tests?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, gradle

I am playing with lucine through Spring-boot. I want to set the folder to the build folder because of test and permisions.

this is my code for now:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.search.default.indexBase: ${LUCINE_FOLDER:/data/index/default}

Later on when deploy, I can easily control it by env variable LUCINE_FOLDER

I want it to be something like:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.search.default.indexBase: ${LUCINE_FOLDER:build/index/default}

I am using gradle as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by local-heap:

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider: local-heap